# NPM still looking for deleted dependency

Tags: npm

I deleted some module folders that I had previously npm installed into a module. I also manually removed their entries in my module's package.json. Then, npm would still look for those deleted folders so I re-created the folders and npm uninstalled them, which succeeded. Is there another way to "clear" npm's graph?

Answer (score 0):

Try running `npm cache clean --force` and then see if the problem still persists. S If would help if you posted your `package.json` file so that we could see if any problems exist.

Comment: Cool thanks Amit. I did resolve the issue but in a work-around kind of way. If I encounter the issue in the future I'll try this command!